# How to play audio recorded file from ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

i am developing an application of Call recording . it record the call and save it in Phone memory(file Manager) and after saving audio file, i managed to show the recorded file in list View. I want to know how to play the audio file through list View. how can i do this.?

Answer (score 3):

You can play it like below.

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                playSong(MEDIA_PATH + files.get(position));
            }
        });
```

and here is your playSong method.

```
private void playSong(String songPath) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(songPath);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

So your full code will looke something like this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    // this will show the recorded files into ListVIew
    private List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    File list[] = file.listFiles();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        myList.add(list[i].getName());
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, files);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        playSong(MEDIA_PATH + myList.get(position));
    }

});

private void playSong(String songPath) {
            try {
                mp.reset();
                mp.setDataSource(songPath);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name), e.getMessage());
            }
        }

}
```

where mp is your media player object `private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();` and MEDIA_PATH is your folder path where you have your all recording like,

```
private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AudioRecorder/");
```

Comment: playSong(MEDIA_PATH + myList.get(position)); plz what is myList.get(..) is for?

Comment: @user1688214, mylist is your list array that you have used for listing your item from sdcard to listview.

Comment: Post your code if you want more help, because without seeing it i can't help you.

Comment: Okay use `files` instead of `myList`.

Comment: Yes it works. like i said i can get the list of saved files. i just want to play this audio files

Comment: i am also getting the list Item position through Toast

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);

    // this will show the recorded files into ListVIew
    final String[] files = new File("mnt/sdcard/Audio File/").list();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, files);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

         //checking the position of item in list
        Object listItem =     listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+listItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
}
```

Comment: playSong(MEDIA_PATH + files.get(position)); i have changed as you said but after changing this. it gets error and it ask to change it into  playSong(MEDIA_PATH + files.length);